# Minecraft: When constantly mining cobblestone, how many seconds does a stone pickaxe last for?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making an advanced cobblestone generator where it dispenses a new stone pickaxe to you when your current one breaks. As there is no way in vanilla survival to detect what the player is holding it's going to dispense the new pickaxe based off of when it dispensed the previous one.

How many stone-mining-seconds does a stone pickaxe last for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time a stone pickaxe takes to break 1 block of cobblestone is 0.75 seconds. A stone pickaxe can break 132 blocks without breaking, so the total theoretical time is 0.75*132 = 99 seconds. However since cobblestone generators take a short time to generate a new block, you will need to experiment to find the best time.

Comment: Also tweak the generator's design to make up for server lag, redstone updates, lava flow glitches, etc.